# Probability of E occurring by SOMEONE if given P(event) and number of people

Tags: probability

The odds of flipping heads is $\frac{1}{2}$

The odds of flipping heads 5 times in a row is $(\frac{1}{2})^5$

But, given 50 people (or use $n$ people), what are the odds SOMEONE flips heads 5 times in a row?

This concept was from this book.    Odds of beating the stock market a 15 years in a row is low.  But, the odds of SOMEONE beating the market 15 years is actually like 75%.  I want to do that math.
[http://www.amazon.com/The-Drunkards-Walk-Randomness-Rules/dp/0307275175](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307275175)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it the opposite way: what are the odds that none of the 50 people get 5 heads? This is $(1 - (1/2)^5)^{50}$. So if you take one minus that, you get the probability that at least one person gets 5 heads. You can approximate using Poisson distribution if you like, with rate parameter equal to $50/2^5 = 25/16$. Of course you can replace $50$ with $n$ in all the calculations above.

Comment: Perfect.  How could I forget the ol' 1-P ?  It seems that was the crux of my entire undergrad Prob. course!  Thanks.

Comment: @JackOfAll You can compute the probability of exactly $m$ people getting $5$ heads, which is ${n \choose m} (1/2^5)^m (1 - 1/2^5)^{n-m}$ and sum for $m = 1$ to $m = n$. However this is not as computationally efficient as the ol' $1 - P$ approach as you call it.

Comment: Yes, the ol' Bernoulli trial (or binomial trial).  I like the first method just fine.